# Is there a way that I can get back my accidently deleted code in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

A couple of days ago, I was copying and pasting my code into a new class.  While the entire code was selected, I hit the backspace key.  The entire code deleted, and I did not realize.  My computer then died.  Today, I opened it back up, and none of the code was there.  The only thing that remained was an empty file.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Try to right click on the file empty file in package explorer, and then select team->Show Local History. Might allow you to show an older version of the file.

Comment: I don't suppose you're using a VCS?

Answer (score 2):

The two comments cover most of it. There are only 3 places your code could possibly be. If you checked them all and none of them have it, you're out of luck.

- Eclipse Local History

Right click the file in the package explorer and pick the 'Restore from local history...' option. Hurry up, eclipse auto-removes local history that's older than 7 days!

- VCS

If you're using version control and you checked this in before, it's a simple restore away. For example, `git checkout path/to/the/file.java` would do it. You'd have to explain which VCS system you are using and how are you accessing it (via eclipse teams, via e.g. Fork.app, via the command line, etc).

- Backups

You're using a computer. It should have backups. These backups need to run automatically and preferably be going 'off site' (to a place that you do not live, you don't want a fire or some serious burglary to mean you have lost both your system *and* your backup!). If you don't have that, you're, uh, well, I don't want to insult you, so you should find some suitable insult that describes a very silly person and then yell that at a mirror.

The only excuse to not have backups for a system is if the system does *everything* in the cloud. Chromebooks really don't need it for example. If you're programming, unless it's some fancy cloud-based programming layout, this does not apply to you, and therefore you should be finding a mirror right about now if you don't have a backup solution in place.

There are open source tools like [arq](https://www.arqbackup.com) where you fully control where the data goes. Various NAS (Network-Attached-Storage) systems have the option to sync with another NAS elsewhere over the network, so buy one for yourself *and* for a friend, and be each other's backup buddy. Or just toss some money at it; services like [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com) offer fixed fee backups and offer client side encryption if that's a worry for you.